# The ManifestMerger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm a beginner and have been following tutorials to build an Android Application with the help of AndroidStudio. I incurred an error while running a code today and it us as follow:

`:app:processDebugManifest

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs'

I'm attaching the manifest.xml and the build.gradle files here:

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
'<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aysha.bookhub"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:version-code="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<application
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label,name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BookHub">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

'

### build.gradle

'plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aysha.bookhub"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}'

The logcat window appears like:

```
2021-05-30 11:54:53.621 738-2456/? D/audio_route: Apply path: low-latency-playback speaker
2021-05-30 11:54:53.622 738-2456/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
2021-05-30 11:54:53.646 572-572/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1600 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
2021-05-30 11:54:53.650 1600-3832/? D/CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 0
2021-05-30 11:54:53.650 1600-3832/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 420
2021-05-30 11:54:53.650 1600-3832/? D/CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
2021-05-30 11:54:53.651 572-572/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker::IServicetracker sid=u:r:system_server:s0 pid=1600 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
2021-05-30 11:54:53.653 1600-2459/? V/UsbDeviceManager: USB UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=android_usb, SEQNUM=139775, ACTION=change '
```

Attaching the eventlog window:
[eventlog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxTYR.png):

```
*

> 2021-05-30 12:14:31.957 2439-2536/? I/AprUploadService.CmUp: DRG_DataGO_358996096126401_1603475532860.zip is upload fail
    2021-05-30 12:14:32.298 2439-2536/? I/AprUploadService.CmUp: DRG_DataGO_358996096126401_1598450541371.zip is upload fail
    2021-05-30 12:14:32.513 2512-2639/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=2,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=true,rssi=0,lastModified=05-30 12:14:29,dataSim=true,networkName=Idea,networkNameData=Idea,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRegistered=true,voiceCapable=true,videoCapable=true,isVolteRegistered=false,voiceNetType=13,comboTypeIcon=2131231841,roamingIcon=0,strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=0,isMobileIms=true,isImsOverWifi=false,volteOption=1,vowifiOption=0
            to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=3,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=true,rssi=0,lastModified=05-30 12:14:29,dataSim=true,networkName=Idea,networkNameData=Idea,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRegistered=true,voiceCapable=true,videoCapable=true,isVolteRegistered=false,voiceNetType=13,comboTypeIcon=2131231841,roamingIcon=0,strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=0,isMobileIms=true,isImsOverWifi=false,volteOption=1,vowifiOption=0
    2021-05-30 12:14:32.514 2512-2639/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updataImsShowOption isMobileIms =true,isImsOverWifi =false,volteOption =1,vowifiOption =0,mSubInfoSize =1
    2021-05-30 12:14:32.514 2512-2639/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131231797 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: true mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: true mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 volteOption: 1 vowifiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0 this: com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.MobileSignalController@6b824fe
    2021-05-30 12:14:32.640 2439-2536/? I/AprUploadService.CmUp: DRG_DataGO_358996096126401_1609514881459.zip is upload fail
```

- 

Comment: can you post your merged manifest log??

Comment: The Event log screen shows up like:
30-05-2021: 11:52 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

11:52 * daemon started successfully

11:53 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\lenovo\BookHub3

11:54 Gradle build failed in 31 s 818 ms

11:54 Failed to start monitoring DRGID19090806851

11:54 Failed to start monitoring DRGID19090806851

Comment: I've attached the Event log window screen and the Logcat window screen above (right now). Kindly do have a look at it. thanking you in advance